# Job Posting: Is this a scam?

Tags: scams, job-offer

I've been applying for jobs recently, and got the following email today:

> From: Charles Edward (redacted@gmail.com)
>   Date: Mon, Mar 9, 2020, 9:41 AM
>   Subject: !!! New message for your Indeed Application !!!
>   To: Redacted (redacted@gmail.com)
>
> Welcome Top Candidate,
>
> The application you submitted has been accepted, This is a full time
>   position but can also be part time, as you will be helping me and your
>   duties will include but are not limited to; Running errands, shopping,
>   supervisions and monitoring, scheduling programs, flights and keeping
>   me up to date with my schedule. You will also act as an alternative
>   telephone correspondence when I'm away, Make regular contacts and
>   drop-offs on my behalf, Handle and monitor my financial activities.
>
> I'm Charles Edward and i'm 62 years old. Am working as an independent
>   real estate attorney and I have been a local and international
>   successful entrepreneur and sometimes invest in the real estate market
>   which makes me travel often within and outside the state working on
>   various independent projects. I will maintain a fair degree of
>   flexibility in terms of working around your other commitments. I will
>   provide clear set of instructions for each task i need done and
>   sufficient funds to cover all errands.
>
> Currently, I am in Toronto meeting with partners. I will be back in 3
>   weeks to arrange a formal interview with you and for necessary
>   paperwork. Please note that this position is not office-based for now
>   because of my frequent travels and tight schedules. The hours vary as
>   some weeks you will be busier than others and you also get to choose
>   your own hours, but the pay stays constant. I have a number of things
>   you could help me with this week if you will be within reach for me.
>
> You will receive Six Hundred and Thirty Dollars ( $620) weekly ,
>   health insurance, 401(k) plan and paid time off which we will discuss
>   in further details when we meet. If you are interested, confirm the
>   below information.
>
> Name :
>
> Full Address :
>
> Apt #:
>
> City/State/ZipCode:
>
> Cell Phone :
>
> Current Occupation :
>
> Email :
>
> Once I have received your application details, I will get back to you
>   with the task for the week ahead. Its important for me to make the
>   necessary steps before I get back from my business trip.
>
> Charles Edward

I don't recall applying for this specific, job listing, but have posted looking for general work at office ans secretarial work

The first thing that struck me as odd is that the email came from a gmail address, not via official indeed channels of any sort, but who knows, maybe they got my email from the application process and reached out directly.

This seems like a scam, I can't find this person on google in my area, you'd expect someone that's a successful attorney to have an online footprint of some sort.

However, if it is a scam, what's the goal here? Identity theft?

If anyone has any ideas, or advice, it'd be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The simplest explanation might be that they collect contact information of gullible people, for further monetization e.g. as "200% confirmed opt-in addresses!!!"

Comment: Yes, this is inevitably a scam. Delete it, block the sender and move on.

Comment: "the application you submitted has been accepted......once I have received your application details" - which is it? :|

Comment: They got me at *"Welcome Top Candidate"*, no need to even read any further...

Answer (score 16):

**Likely mode of the scam:** You'll funnel some/all of the transactions through your own bank account and then the money he sent to you to fund the transactions will bounce or disappear.

He's already laying the groundwork by telling you he has many transactions, frequently out of town, etc. In 3 weeks, he will have an "important opportunity out of the country" so won't do the in-person interview, you will never meet him. But he will be so impressed with you that he will hire you anyway and get started right away.

In fact, if you reply, then he will get started this week- he already said he has some tasks. But since you have not met with him yet- that's in 3 weeks, remember- you have not been able to set up your corporate account with him. But let's get started right away! You get $630 (or is it $620?) and here's a signing bonus also. But you don't have the paperwork yet, so for now, he'll transfer the money to you and you can handle it through your account. The script will be something like this: Send me your account number and your username and password. You know, this is a big international real estate deal worth millions of dollars and the transactions are tens of thousands of dollars, so I can't just Zelle you the money, I need to deposit it directly for you.

Comment: Or he will send you money to "complete his business deals" or something; which is really just sending him irreversible payments through whatever means he chooses.  Then he reverses the money that was sent to you, and you've basically just paid him out of pocket.